# Unable to connect to remote server in FTP in windows application file transfer

Tags: c#, ftp

I am making wpf application, there I am utilizing FTP to Upload documents to server. when I had a go at running my code it throws exception as,

> Unable to connect to Remote server

For testing I am utilizing my companion's PC to transfer pictures

Here is my code alluded from this [site](http://www.vcskicks.com/csharp_ftp_upload.php)

```
    static string ftpServerIP = "address";  
    static string ftpUserID = "admin";
    static string ftpPassword = "***";
    static string ServerPath = "C:/Images";

    private void Upload(string imagePath)
    {
        string info = new FileInfo(imagePath).Name;
        string url = "ftp://" + ftpServerIP + "/" + ServerPath + "/" + info;
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(url));
        request.UseBinary = true;
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;            
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUserID.Normalize(), ftpPassword.Normalize());
        request.UsePassive = true;
        request.UseBinary = true;
        request.KeepAlive = false;
        byte[] fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(imagePath);

        request.ContentLength = fileData.Length;
        try
        {
            using (Stream reqStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                reqStream.Write(fileData, 0, fileData.Length);
                reqStream.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string ImagePath = @"C:\Users\Randy\Pictures\Camera Roll\WIN_20150317_125215.JPG";

        Upload(ImagePath);
    }
```

Comment: Try connecting via the command line. `ftp://1.2.3.4/C:/Images` is not a valid FTP URI

Comment: i tried writing this as `"ftp://1.2.3.4/Images"` but the errror throws at GetRequestStream() method as `Unable to connect to Remote server`

Comment: Have you tried connecting to that server using a standalone FTP client? Because perhaps your machine is really simply unable to connect.